# Elastic Search with Magento on 8080 port

Tags: php, magento, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using elasticsearch for searching in my magento website.

I have install the elastic serch on my server but due to some security reason,

Akamai has blocked the :9200 port.

i have the conversation with Akamai, they are saying you can use :8080 port for running elastic search.

I have tried by changing default port in the elastica library as well as http and non-blocked tcp.

But still it is not working even i am not getting any error in my log files.

Please suggest how we can the implement the same

Below are the some of my finding which i refer.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/host-reference.html

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport

I have also modify path.conf. It would look like mention below:

```
bin/elasticsearch -f -Des.path.conf=/path/to/config/dir
```

That will read /path/to/config/dir/elasticsearch.yml and /path/to/config/dir/elasticsearch.json.

But still i am not able to see output in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to alter the config files, elasticsearch configuration files can be found under ES_HOME/config folder.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html

You will need to alter the "http.port"

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2